# Removing traces by name using plotlyProxy (or accessing output schema in reactive context)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I am attempting to use the `plotlyProxy()` functionality ([Documented here](https://plot.ly/r/plotlyproxy/)) to allow users of a shiny application to add and remove traces with minimal latency.

Adding traces proves to be relatively simple, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to remove traces by name *(I'm only seeing documented examples that remove by trace number)*.

Is there a way to remove traces by name using `plotlyProxy()`?

If not, is there a way that I can parse through the output object to derive what trace numbers are associated with a given name?

I can determine the associated trace number of a given name in an interactive R session using the standard schema indices, but when I attempt to apply the same logic in a shiny application I get an error: *"Error in $.shinyoutput: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed."*

A minimal example is below. Neither observer watching the `Remove` button actually works, but they should give an idea for the functionality I'm trying to achieve.

---

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("TraceName", "Trace Name"),
  actionButton("Add","Add Trace"),
  actionButton("Remove","Remove Trace"),
  plotlyOutput("MyPlot")
)

server <- function(input,output,session) {

  ## Creaing the plot
  output$MyPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly() %>%
      layout(showlegend  = TRUE)
  })

  ## Adding traces is smooth sailing
  observeEvent(input$Add,{
    plotlyProxy("MyPlot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("addTraces", list(x = rnorm(10),y = rnorm(10),
                                          type = "scatter",mode = "markers",
                                          name = input$TraceName))
  })

  ## Ideal Solution (that does not work)
  observeEvent(input$Remove,{
    plotlyProxy("MyPlot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("deleteTraces", input$TraceName)
  })

  ## Trying to extract tracenames throws an error:
  ## Warning: Error in $.shinyoutput: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed.
  observeEvent(input$Remove,{
    TraceNames <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(names(output$MyPlot$x$attrs)),
                                function(x) output$MyPlot$x$attrs[[x]][["name"]]))
    ThisTrace <- which(TraceNames == input$TraceName)

    plotlyProxy("MyPlot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("deleteTraces", ThisTrace)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: App Example]

Comment: maybe you could try `event_data()` to extract the info you need from `MyPlot`.

Comment: Reviewing the definition of `event_data()`in [shiny.R](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/master/R/shiny.R) and the [plotly events example app](https://plot.ly/r/shinyapp-plotly-events/), the closest to what I'm desiring would be having the user click on a plot trace to select it for deletion. This isn't _quite_ what I'm looking for -- programmatic identification that could be extended to remove multiple traces based on a hierarchy of inputs. I appreciate you taking time to make a suggestion though, let me know if you think I may be overlooking something!

Comment: MattSummersgill, @SeGa, please check my edited answer.

Comment: @ismirsehregal That does the trick, thanks so much for making that connection and following up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit** using `plotlyProxy`:

**Update** @SeGa, thanks for adding support to delete traces with duplicated names!

Finally, I found a solution to realize the expected behaviour by adapting this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54825337/9841389). I'm receiving the trace.name / trace.index mapping by using `onRender` from `library(htmlwidgets)` after the remove-button is clicked:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

js <- "function(el, x, inputName){
  var id = el.getAttribute('id');
  var d3 = Plotly.d3;
  $(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
    if (event.name === 'Remove') {
      var out = [];
      d3.select('#' + id + ' g.legend').selectAll('.traces').each(function(){
        var trace = d3.select(this)[0][0].__data__[0].trace;
        out.push([name=trace.name, index=trace.index]);
      });
      Shiny.setInputValue(inputName, out);
    }
  });
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("TraceName", "Trace Name"),
  verbatimTextOutput("PrintTraceMapping"),
  actionButton("Add", "Add Trace"),
  actionButton("Remove", "Remove Trace"),
  plotlyOutput("MyPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$MyPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>%
      layout(showlegend  = TRUE) %>% onRender(js, data = "TraceMapping") 
  })
  
  output$PrintTraceMapping <- renderPrint({unlist(input$TraceMapping)})
  
  observeEvent(input$Add, {
    req(input$TraceName)
    plotlyProxy("MyPlot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("addTraces", list(x = rnorm(10),y = rnorm(10),
                                          type = "scatter",mode = "markers",
                                          name = input$TraceName))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Remove, {
    req(input$TraceName, input$TraceMapping)
    traces <- matrix(input$TraceMapping, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
    indices <- as.integer(traces[traces[, 1] == input$TraceName, 2])
    plotlyProxy("MyPlot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("deleteTraces", indices)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Useful articles in this context:

[shiny js-events](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html)

[plotly addTraces](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyaddtraces)

[plotly deleteTraces](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlydeletetraces)

---

**Solution for Shiny Modules** using `plotlyProxy`:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

js <- "function(el, x, data){
  var id = el.getAttribute('id');
  var d3 = Plotly.d3;
  $(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
    if (event.name.indexOf('Remove') > -1) {
      var out = [];
      d3.select('#' + id + ' g.legend').selectAll('.traces').each(function(){
        var trace = d3.select(this)[0][0].__data__[0].trace;
        out.push([name=trace.name, index=trace.index]);
      });
      Shiny.setInputValue(data.ns + data.x, out);
    }
  });
}"

plotly_ui_mod <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textInput(ns("TraceName"), "Trace Name"),
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("PrintTraceMapping")),
    actionButton(ns("Add"), "Add Trace"),
    actionButton(ns("Remove"), "Remove Trace"),
    plotlyOutput(ns("MyPlot"))
  )
}

plotly_server_mod <- function(input, output, session) {
  sessionval <- session$ns("")
  
  output$MyPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>%
      layout(showlegend  = TRUE) %>% onRender(js, data = list(x = "TraceMapping", 
                                                              ns = sessionval))
  })
  output$PrintTraceMapping <- renderPrint({unlist(input$TraceMapping)})
  observeEvent(input$Add, {
    req(input$TraceName)
    plotlyProxy("MyPlot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("addTraces", list(x = rnorm(10),y = rnorm(10),
                                          type = "scatter",mode = "markers",
                                          name = input$TraceName))
  })
  observeEvent(input$Remove, {
    req(input$TraceName, input$TraceMapping)
    traces <- matrix(input$TraceMapping, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
    indices <- as.integer(traces[traces[, 1] == input$TraceName, 2])
    plotlyProxy("MyPlot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("deleteTraces", indices)
  })
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  plotly_ui_mod("plotly_mod")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(plotly_server_mod, "plotly_mod")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

**Previous Solution** avoiding `plotlyProxy`:

I came here via this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53822696/add-plotly-traces-dynamically-on-shiny/53829576#53829576).

You were explicitly asking for `plotlyProxy()` so I'm not sure if this is helpful to you, but here is a workaround to realize the expected behaviour via updating the data provided to `plot_ly()` instead of using `plotlyProxy()`:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(inputId="myTraces", label="Trace names", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE, options = list('plugins' = list('remove_button'), 'create' = TRUE, 'persist' = TRUE, placeholder = "...add or remove traces")),
  plotlyOutput("MyPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  myData <- reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$myTraces, {
    tmpList <- list()
    
    for(myTrace in input$myTraces){
      tmpList[[myTrace]] <- data.frame(name = myTrace, x = rnorm(10),y = rnorm(10))
    }
    
    myData(do.call("rbind", tmpList))
    
    return(NULL)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  output$MyPlot <- renderPlotly({
    if(is.null(myData())){
      plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
    } else {
      plot_ly(myData(), x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~name, type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>%
        layout(showlegend  = TRUE)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: +1. The only problem I still see though, is that it will only delete 1 trace at a time, so if you have multiple traces with name "xx" you will have to delete "xx" multiple times.

Comment: @SeGa improvements are always welcome - Thanks for sharing! I'll merge it into the code block at the top, so that future readers can simply copy and paste.

Comment: Great, then I also included a solution for shiny modules.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the names attributes of the traces, and I think the `deleteTrace` function is not able to delete by name. Based on the reference it just deletes **based on [index](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlydeletetraces)**.

I tried to implement something for Shiny, which records the added traces in a dataframe and adds an index to them. For deletion, it matches the given names with the dataframe and gives those indeces to the delete method of `plotlyProxyInvoke`, but it is not working correctly. *Maybe someone could add some insight into why this is happening?*

One **problem** seems to be the legend, which is showing wrong labels after deletion and I dont think that plotly and R/shiny are keeping the same indices of the traces, which leads to strange behaviour. So this code definitly needs some fixing.

--
I included a small JQuery snippet, which records all the traces of the plot and sends them to a `reactiveVal()`. Interestingly, it differs from the data.frame, that listens to the `AddTraces` event. There will always be one remaining trace in the plot.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(
    "$(document).on('shiny:value', function(event) {
    var a = $('.scatterlayer.mlayer').children();
    if (a.length > 0) {
    var text = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    text += a[i].className.baseVal + '<br>';
    }
    Shiny.onInputChange('plotlystr', text);
    }
    });"
))),
textInput("TraceName", "Trace Name"),
actionButton("Add","Add Trace"),
actionButton("Remove","Remove Trace by Name"),
plotlyOutput("MyPlot"),
splitLayout(
  verbatimTextOutput("printplotly"),
  verbatimTextOutput("printreactive")
)
  )

server <- function(input,output,session) {

  ## Reactive Plot
  plt <- reactive({
    plot_ly() %>%
      layout(showlegend  = T)
  })
  ## Reactive Value for Added Traces
  addedTrcs <- reactiveValues(tr = NULL, id = NULL, df = NULL)

  ## Creaing the plot
  output$MyPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plt()
  })

  ## Adding traces is smooth sailing
  observeEvent(input$Add,{
    req(input$TraceName)
    plotlyProxy("MyPlot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("addTraces", list(x = rnorm(10),y = rnorm(10),
                                          type = "scatter",mode = "markers", colors ="blue",
                                          name = input$TraceName))
  })
  ## Adding trace to reactive
  observeEvent(input$Add, {
    req(input$TraceName)
    x <- input$TraceName
    addedTrcs$id <- c(addedTrcs$id, length(addedTrcs$id))
    addedTrcs$tr <- c(addedTrcs$tr, x)
    addedTrcs$df <- data.frame(id=addedTrcs$id, tr=addedTrcs$tr, stringsAsFactors = F)
  })

  ## Remove Trace from Proxy by NAME
  observeEvent(input$Remove,{
    req(input$TraceName %in% addedTrcs$tr)
    ind = which(addedTrcs$df$tr == input$TraceName)
    ind = addedTrcs$df[ind,"id"]

    plotlyProxy("MyPlot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("deleteTraces", as.integer(ind))
  })  

  ## Remove Trace from Reactive
  observeEvent(input$Remove, {
    req(input$TraceName %in% addedTrcs$df$tr)  

    whichInd <- which(addedTrcs$tr == input$TraceName)
    addedTrcs$df <- addedTrcs$df[-whichInd,]
    addedTrcs$id <- addedTrcs$id[-whichInd]
    addedTrcs$tr <- addedTrcs$tr[-whichInd]

    req(nrow(addedTrcs$df)!=0)
    addedTrcs$df$id <- 0:(nrow(addedTrcs$df)-1)
  })


  tracesReact <- reactiveVal()
  observe({
    req(input$plotlystr)
    traces <- data.frame(traces=strsplit(input$plotlystr, split = "<br>")[[1]])
    tracesReact(traces)
  })
  output$printplotly <- renderPrint({
    req(tracesReact())
    tracesReact()
  })

  ## Print Reactive Value (added traces)
  output$printreactive <- renderPrint({
    req(addedTrcs$df)
    addedTrcs$df
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears the Plotly.D3 method has been depreciated and no longer works in the above code. I was able to replicate a simple solution with the below code.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

js <- "function(el){
  $(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
    if (event.name === 'Remove') {
      var traceName = document.getElementById('TraceName').value
      var plotlyData = document.getElementById('MyPlot').data
      plotlyData.forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (item.name === traceName){
          Plotly.deleteTraces('MyPlot', index);
        }
      });
      
    }
  });
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("TraceName", "Trace Name"),
  actionButton("Remove", "Remove Trace"),
  plotlyOutput("MyPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$MyPlot <- renderPlotly({
    print("renderPlotlyRan")
    plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>%
      add_markers(x = rnorm(10),y = rnorm(10), name = "Trace1") %>% 
      add_markers(x = rnorm(10),y = rnorm(10), name = "Trace2") %>% 
      add_markers(x = rnorm(10),y = rnorm(10), name = "Trace3") %>% 
      add_markers(x = rnorm(10),y = rnorm(10), name = "Trace4") %>% 
      layout(showlegend  = TRUE) %>% 
      htmlwidgets::onRender(x = ., jsCode = js) 
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```