# How to dynamically add AND remove overlay from plotly histogram in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

This R code produces a plotly plot that overlays two histograms together.

```
fig <- plot_ly(alpha = 0.6)
fig <- fig %>% add_histogram(x = ~rnorm(500))
fig <- fig %>% add_histogram(x = ~rnorm(500) + 1)
fig <- fig %>% layout(barmode = "overlay")

fig
```

I have a `shiny` app that contains variable categorical input. Based on user selections, I want to add or remove categories to plot in the histogram. It would be great to be able to add or remove overlays dynamically. Right now it seems like adding overlays dynamically could be possible. Removing them seems more difficult. I'd like to know if my requirement possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** @FreyGeospatial clarified, that he wants to add/remove traces (I was confused of the wording using `overlay`).

The easiest way to dynamically add and remove traces is to create a data.frame in long format providing a category column.

In `plot_ly` you can use `split` or `color` to create traces based on this column.
To remove traces you can filter categories from a reactive dataset and re-render the plot:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

DF <- data.frame(values = rnorm(2500), category = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 500))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(inputId = "barmode",
                 label = "barmode",
                 choices = c("group", "overlay", "stack"),
                 selected = "overlay"),
  selectizeInput(inputId = "category",
                 label = "category",
                 choices = unique(DF$category), selected = LETTERS[1:3], multiple = TRUE),
  plotlyOutput("myPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  filteredDF <- reactive({
    DF[DF$category %in% input$category,]
  })
  
  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    fig <- plot_ly(data = filteredDF(), x = ~ values, split = ~ category, alpha = 0.6, type = "histogram")
    fig <- fig %>% layout(barmode = input$barmode)
    fig
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

As an alternative to re-rendering the plot you could use plotlyProxy and the [addTraces JS function](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyaddtraces) please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138568/removing-traces-by-name-using-plotlyproxy-or-accessing-output-schema-in-reactiv/53831080#53831080). This is faster than re-rendering but less intutive using plotly's R API.

---

Please run:

```
install.packages("listviewer")
schema()
```

and navigate:
object ► traces ► bar ► layoutAttributes ► barmode

To find the barmode description:

default: group

> Determines how bars at the same location coordinate are displayed on
> the graph. With *stack*, the bars are stacked on top of one another
> With *relative*, the bars are stacked on top of one another, with
> negative values below the axis, positive values above With *group*,
> the bars are plotted next to one another centered around the shared
> location. With *overlay*, the bars are plotted over one another, you
> might need to an *opacity* to see multiple bars.

Comment: Hi- this is useful code, but maybe I should rephrase- I'm looking to add and remove categories from the plot, as in add and remove trace0 and trace1 dynamically

Comment: Please see my edit.