# Is it possible to change the colorway in a rendered plot?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have a shiny app with a slightly larger plotly graphic. I would like to change the colors of the traces without re-rendering the plot. Is there any way to do this?

Minimal working example without shiny app

```
library(plotly)

trace_0 <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
trace_1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
trace_2 <- rnorm(100, mean = -5)
x <- c(1:100)

data <- data.frame(x, trace_0, trace_1, trace_2)

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~trace_0, name = 'trace 0', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_1, name = 'trace 1', mode = 'lines') 
fig
# update colors
layout(fig,  colorway = c("yellow","green"))
```

Now i tried it in a (minimal) shiny app

```
ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow( 
    plotlyOutput("plot")
    ),
  fluidRow(
    actionButton("changeColor", "Change Color")
  )
)

server= function(input,output, session){
  output[["plot"]] = renderPlotly({
    trace_0 <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
    trace_1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
    trace_2 <- rnorm(100, mean = -5)
    x <- c(1:100)
    
    data <- data.frame(x, trace_0, trace_1, trace_2)
    
    fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~trace_0, name = 'trace 0', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') 
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_1, name = 'trace 1', mode = 'lines') 
    fig
  })
  plotProxy <- plotlyProxy(outputId="plot")
  
  observeEvent(input[["changeColor"]],{
    print("Color should change now (but does not)")
    plotlyProxyInvoke(plotProxy, "relayout",
                     colorway = c("yellow","green"))
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Tried also restyle, or argument

```
list(colorway = c("yellow","green")),
```

but nothing worked out for me.
I would like to prevent a re-render of the graphic, because it takes about 4-5 seconds

Comment: I left another approach below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `restyle` the line color of a scatter trace via `plotlyProxyInvoke`.

Please run `schema()` and navigate: `traces > scatter > attributes > line > color`

Checking `schema()` is useful to prepare `plotlyProxyInvoke` calls using valid attributes.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow( 
    plotlyOutput("plot")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    actionButton("changeColor", "Change Color")
  )
)

server= function(input,output, session){
  output[["plot"]] = renderPlotly({
    trace_0 <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
    trace_1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
    trace_2 <- rnorm(100, mean = -5)
    x <- c(1:100)
    
    data <- data.frame(x, trace_0, trace_1, trace_2)
    
    fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~trace_0, name = 'trace 0', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') 
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_1, name = 'trace 1', mode = 'lines') 
    fig
  })
  plotProxy <- plotlyProxy(outputId="plot")
  
  observeEvent(input[["changeColor"]],{
    plotlyProxyInvoke(plotProxy, "restyle", list(line = list(color = "yellow")), list(0))
    plotlyProxyInvoke(plotProxy, "restyle", list(line = list(color = "lightgreen")), list(1))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi ismirsehregal. What is `schema` please?

Comment: Hi @StéphaneLaurent - please see `?plotly::schema()`. The description says: The schema contains valid attributes names, their value type, default values (if any), and min/max values (if applicable). You'll need `library(listviewer)` to use it. Cheers

Comment: Hi, this helped a lot thank you. Also `schema()` I did not know and really helps. Nevertheless, the syntax of plotproxy invoke is still a mystery to me. The last argument (`list(0)`/`list(1)`) then targets the trace? Does this also work via id, just want to understand it, or can you read something about the syntax somewhere?

Comment: Please see plotly's [function reference](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrestyle): `Plotly.restyle(graphDiv, update [, traceIndices])`. Referring to the traces by name is a [littly tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53831080/9841389).

Answer (score 0):

I would define colors as reactiveValues. Put rnorm outside plot function so that it isn't run every time you refresh the plot

```
library(plotly)

ui = fluidPage(
fluidRow( 
plotlyOutput("plot")
),
fluidRow(
actionButton("changeColor", "Change Color")
)
)

server= function(input,output, session){

plot_col <- reactiveValues()
plot_col$a <- 'red'
plot_col$b <- 'blue'

trace_0 <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
trace_1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
trace_2 <- rnorm(100, mean = -5)

output[["plot"]] = renderPlotly({

x <- c(1:100)

data <- data.frame(x, trace_0, trace_1, trace_2)

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~trace_0, name = 'trace 0', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = plot_col$a)) 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_1, name = 'trace 1', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = plot_col$b)) 
fig
})
plotProxy <- plotlyProxy(outputId="plot")

observeEvent(input[["changeColor"]],{

  plot_col$a <- 'green'
  plot_col$b <- 'yellow'

})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I said, this is only a minimal example. The "real" plot has about a million points and therefore takes a bit longer to render.

I implemented it similar to your example, but in this way a color change takes a long time (because the whole plot is regenerated). I had the hope to get it faster with the use of plotly proxy, so updating the plot not regenerating....